# Angular Material md-button ripple on mousedown instead of click

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material2

I have been using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io) and I am running into a problem. The documentation is very vague about a lot of things so hopefully someone can help me here. Here is what I am trying to do:

Currently, if I put this into my HTML,

```
<button md-button>Click me</button>
```

the ripple effect happens on mouseup. Is there any way that I can change that to mousedown?

This is what I've tried:

```
<button 
    md-button 
    #nextButton 
    (click)="alertHelloWorld()" 
    (mousedown)="nextButton.focus()">
Hello World! I should ripple on mousedown
</button>
```

this doesn't seem to be working though.

Any help?

Comment: The ripple is a feedback of the click. If you implement it like that you will break this.

Comment: So in what way do you suggest I get the ripple on mousedown?

Comment: You should not, the ripple is a visual indicator of a click.

Comment: I didn't ask if I should or not, I'm asking how to do it. If you could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `MdRipple` directive to trigger it manually.

Component:

```
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild(MdRipple) ripple: MdRipple;

  rippleButton () {
    this.ripple.launch(0, 0, { centered: true });
  }
```

Template:

```
<button md-ripple (mousedown)="rippleButton()"> ... </button>
```

NgModule:

```
imports: [
  ...
  MdRippleModule,
  ...
],
```

I haven't tested the code, but looking at the documentation on the GitHub repository gives an idea that this should work:

[MdRipple demo](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/2bf702452717f43634603f5335daffee9701f31b/src/demo-app/ripple)

[MdRipple documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/2bf702452717f43634603f5335daffee9701f31b/src/lib/core/ripple)

Comment: Thanks! The button ripples on mousedown now, but also mouseup. Is there a way to prevent default to the mouseup or click event?